# iOS - Add view without knowing its size

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying, programmatically, to add subviews to my view. The process goes as follows:

1) Fetch an array of medias from the web

2) If it is a picture, build a `UIImageView` and add it to the bottom of the view. If it is text, build a `UITextView` and add it to the bottom of the view

3) Repeat step 2 until the end of the array

The problems:

- How do I create the views if I don't know what will be the height of them? It seems that to add a view I need to specify its frame.
- How do I add each view to the bottom of the already existing views?

Thanks in advance,
Tiago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've figured an answer to both my questions:

### How do I create the views if I don't know what will be the height of them?

After getting the content from web, call `.layoutIfNeeded()` to lay out the view. You are now able to use the `contentSize` of the view to draw it. See example below.

### How do I add each view to the bottom of the already existing views?

2 ways:

1) Use a UITableView, easier and more reliable

2) Have a variable to hold the bottom of the stack of views, and update it every time you add a new view. Use this variable to decide where to add a new view.

Here's the code with 2):

```
var yAxis: CGFloat = 0

var textContent: String = "" {
        didSet{
            var textView = UITextView()
            textView.text = textContent
            textView.layoutIfNeeded()
            textView.frame.size = CGSizeMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, textView.contentSize.height)

            textView.frame.origin.y = yAxis
            yAxis += textView.contentSize.height
            view.addSubview(textView)
        }
 }
```

Thanks to @Dhruv Ramani for the hint.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know the size of the view, call the `sizeToFit` and `layoutIfNeeded` method after adding the view. Here's the code:

**Objective-C :**

```
[superView addSubview: view];

[view sizeToFit]; 
[view layoutIfNeeded];
```

**Swift :**

```
superView.addSubview(view)
view.sizeToFit()
view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always create the view with a zero-sized frame (`CGRectZero`) and set its frame later once you know it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a UITableView to implement this feature. The tableView is normally used for displaying 'N' number of items. You can create two custom cells,

1 for displaying an Image

2nd for displaying a textview.

And then based on the item type of the Array you can reuse these custom cells.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are looking to initialize and then add the view as a subview. If so, you can do the following:

```
UIView *yourView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
//Note - CGRectZero is equivalent to CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)
[superView addSubview: yourView];
```

Now when you are ready to resize the view, you can do so as follows:

```
[yourView setFrame: CGRectMake(newXOrigin, newYOrigin, newWidth, newHeight)];
```

or alternatively

```
[yourView sizeToFit];
```